# Delete Alt-F2 history

Tags: gnome, delete, history

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I delete the command line history from the dash?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/135931/how-can-i-delete-the-command-line-history-from-the-dash)

Can anybody tell me configuration or file address where it is (on GNOME 3).
On gnome2 it was in config `/apps/gnome-settings/gnome-panel/history-gnome-run`

Comment: Hello!... Anybody knows answer?

Comment: "org.gnome.gnome-panel.run-dialog" is the correct entry to clear via dconf-editor

Answer (score 1):

1. Install dconf-tools

   ```
   sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
   ```
2. Run *dconf Editor* and navigate to `/desktop/unity/runner/history`:

   [image]
3. Click the *Set to Default* button and then log out and log back in.