# How can I delete the command line history from the dash?

Tags: unity-dash, privacy, history

When accessing the command line by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> it opens the dash and displays a history of previous commands which have been entered. How can this history be removed?

I've tried using Activity Log Manager but that only seems to be relevant to deleting the history of recent files rather than these commands.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can clear <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> history in dconf editor.

**Install dconf editor:**

Hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and run the following command:

`sudo apt-get install dconf-tools`

Or search for "dconf-tools" in Software Center and install it from there.

**Clearing History:**

Once installed, Hit super key (windows key) to open Unity dash and search for "dconf editor" and open it.

Navigate to `Desktop > Unity > runner` and click on "Set to default" in lower right corner. That's it!

[image]

Comment: I found that this doesn't take effect until you log out and then back in - and if you do anything to change the value in the meantime like running another alt-F2 command, the entire old value will be persisted back to dconf, so edit the value, log out, and then back in again.

Comment: In ubuntu 20.04 it's `org.gnome.shell.command-history`

Answer (score 0):

1.How to delete history without any trace

```
history -d $((HISTCMD-1)) && history -d NO_of_History_you_want_to_delete
```

2.if you want to excute a command without leaving any trace.

```
history -d $((HISTCMD-1)) && type_your_command_here_and_execute
```